# iOS 7 replicate home screen like animation to present/push a view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, view, ios7

I would like to replicate the animation effect available on the iOS 7 home screen when launching an app and when closing the app. When launching the app, the app appears to expand to full scene from a point and when closing the app it appears to contract from full screen to a point. I am not sure what is the official name for this animation.

I would like to do something similar in my app. I would like to present/push a view controller B from view controller A with an animation effect similar to the iOS 7 home screen animation mentioned above.

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: The effect that I need is similar to the one in the feedly iOS 7 app. when the user touches a news story title on home screen, details about that news story are displayed in another view and this other view appears to "emanate" from the the touch point. And when the user closes the second view it appears to collapse to the touch point. I have searched a lot but could not find a solution. please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually do that explicitly. The closest you can do is trigger a `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` block, and making sure the `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:]` is set, so you can animate the new view controller/source controller in or out, then you can do the barebones `[self presentViewController:X animated:NO completion:nil];` once you're done.

Comment: the block based animation would rather be recommended from iOS4+. (now, we are at iOS7)

Comment: It looked like he wasn't familiar with iOS-SDK as much. So I gave him the barebones way without overcomplicating it. Of course there's CATransition and whatnot..

Answer (score 0):

You can do similar things also with UICollectionViews animating its layout. And that would also include the push segue navigations, so if you are using UINavigationBarController it will animate accordingly as well.

A nice example is iOS 7 Photos app. If you think that animations between Years/Collections/Moments/Photos is what you need, Apple gave a presentation on that at WWDC 2013.

Comment: I am not using collection views. I have a table view in View A and when user touches a button on View A, the view B should "emanate"from view A. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me.

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/

The author has a github for this.

https://github.com/jbradforddillon/TransitioningExample

All thanks and reps to bradford dillon.